# PHP How can get the namespace of class method parameter?

Tags: php, parameters, namespaces

Hello i try many things to catch the namespace of an parameter function but nothing.

```
public function table(Homes $homes) { // <---------- Homes
    return $homes->get('home');
}
```

I try with ReflectionClass but give me only the name $homes not the Homes namespace.

Comment: `Homes` is not a "namespace", it's a class name. `get_class($homes)`

Comment: No i try to get like: $reflector = new ReflectionClass('System\Classes\Architecture'); i want set the object with reflection before make new Homes

Comment: Yes it's a namespace the Homes it's a namespace 'Class System\Classes\Architecture\Homes'

Comment: @JohnStamoutsos Please edit your question and try to clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve. Right now, your question and your comments look quite inconsistent to me and I don't really understand your question. If you're trying to get the namespace of a class without the class name itself, it's as simple as `(new ReflectionClass($home))->getNamespaceName();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible:

```
$method         = new ReflectionMethod('classDeclaringMethodTable', 'table');

// ReflectionMethod::getParameters() returns an *array*
// of ReflectionParameter instances; get the first one
$parameter      = $declaringMethod->getParameters()[0];

// Get a ReflectionClass instance for the parameter hint
$parameterClass = $parameter->getClass();
```

And then at this point, it depends on exactly what you want ...

```
// Returns ONLY the namespace under which class Homes was declared
$parameterClass->getNamespaceName();

// Returns the fully qualified class name of Homes
// (i.e. namespace + original name; it may've been aliased)
$parameterClass->getName();
```

I've used multiple variables to make it easier to follow, but it can easily be a one-liner with method chaining.

Comment: Yes baby, that's it!

Comment: Thanks, this set me on the right path. getClass() has been deprecated, though, but I found what I needed with $parameterClass->getType()->getName() (fully qualified namespaced name).  Some of this is undocumented, but the commentary was helpful in https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectiontype.php

Answer (score 1):

You should be careful with the PHP version you're using.

In PHP 7.1, `\ReflectionParameter::getType()` returns an instance of `ReflectionNamedType` or `null`:

```
public function hello(Foo $bar);
```

In PHP 8.0, `\ReflectionParameter::getType()` may also return an instance of `ReflectionUnionType`.

```
public function hello(Foo|Bar $baz);
```

In PHP 8.1, `\ReflectionParameter::getType()` may also return an instance of `\ReflectionIntersectionType`.

```
public function hello(Foo&Bar $baz);
```

So in recent PHP versions, you cannot only support a single class FQDN (the fully qualified class name).

To give an implementation example, in a Symfony project, you may know whether a `\ReflectionType` is an entity using the following code:

```
private function isEntity(\ReflectionNamedType|\ReflectionUnionType|\ReflectionIntersectionType|null $type): bool
{
    if (null === $type) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($type instanceof \ReflectionNamedType && str_contains($type->getName(), '\\Entity\\')) {
        return true;
    }

    if ($type instanceof \ReflectionUnionType || $type instanceof \ReflectionIntersectionType) {
        foreach ($type->getTypes() as $subType) {
            if ($this->isEntity($subType)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

*(This code is used in a unit test that checks whether resources received in symfony controllers are well protected using `#[IsGranted]` attributes, you can check its full code [here](https://gist.github.com/ninsuo/b08a9c6347a2705a7aceaeca12ff26e6)).*

Comment: what is FQDN stands for?

Comment: the fully qualified class name (e.g. the class name prefixed by its namespace)

Comment: I am updating the answer. Short abbreviation confuses the reader if they are not familiar with the term.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need to get class name with namespace...
In PHP namespace is part of class name. And there is simple build-in function *get_class($object)*.

Comment: No i try to get like:  $reflector = new ReflectionClass('System\Classes\Architecture'); i want set the object with reflection